# Get list of routes of a Flask function

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, flask

I am using Flask and Bootstrap 3, I would like to get a list of all the urls generated by a function, so that I can link to all of them in the bootstrap theme .

e.g:

```
/programme/23022014
/programme/24022014
/programme/25022014
```

Here is my function :

```
@cache.cached(timeout=86400)
@app.route('/programme/<prog_id>')
def programme(prog_id):
    daily_bands= my_location + "/static/data/bandsdaily/"  + prog_id  + ".json"
    event_details = []
    with open(daily_bands) as f:
            for line in f:
                data = json.loads(line)
            event_details.append(data)
    return render_template('index.html', data=event_details)
```

I tried to put `prog_id` variable and pass it using `render_template`, it doesn't work, and I tried to use `url_for()` but I think this latter is used for other purposes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to use `url_for()` here; it'll generate the various `/programme/<prog_id>` urls for you. Presumably you have a series of `prog_id.json` files in your `bandsdaily` directory that you want to link to here.

You'll need to get a list of all possible `prog_id` values and use `url_for()` with each:

```
{% for prog_id in prog_ids %}
    {{ url_for('programme', prog_id=prog_id) }}
{% endfor %}
```

and pass in your a `prog_ids` as a list to the template:

```
from flask import abort, render_template
import os.path


@cache.cached(timeout=86400)
@app.route('/programme/<prog_id>')
def programme(prog_id):
    path = os.path.join(my_location, "static/data/bandsdaily/")
    prog_ids = [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in os.listdir(path)]
    if prog_id not in prog_ids:
        # no such file, return a not-found status
        abort(404)

    daily_bands = os.path.join(my_location, prog_id  + ".json")
    with open(daily_bands) as f:
        event_details = [json.loads(l) for l in f]

    return render_template('index.html', data=event_details, prog_ids=prog_ids)
```

This version of your view also returns a `404 Not Found` status if a `prog_id` file doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks it was fast, detailed and very helpful. I added/modified this piece of code:

`prog_ids = [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename))]`

`prog_ids.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d%m%Y'))`